# Accordion Panel not working

Tags: jsf, primefaces, xhtml

i have just 2 xhtml pages . first page contains a form with a button and i have set the navigation  rule in such a way that upon this button click , i'm just returning "success" from the backing been and as a result the second page opens which contains the accordion panel . But the problem is , after the page has been loaded the page freezes and you know the tabs present in the accordion panel cannot be expanded . (i.e) accordion panel fails to work.

page 1:

```
<h:form>
<p:commandButton action="#{Bean.check}" value="click"></p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

page 2:

```
<h:form>
<p:accordionPanel  activeIndex="#{Bean.store}">
        <p:tab title="tab1">
            <h:commandLink value="click"></h:commandLink>
            <br />
            <h:commandLink value="next"></h:commandLink>
            <br />
            <h:commandLink value="previous"></h:commandLink>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="tab2" id="jun" >
            <p:commandLink value="click" action="override.xhtml"
                >
                                    <p:effect event="click" type="highlight"></p:effect>

            </p:commandLink>

            <br />
            <p:commandLink value="next" action="header.xhtml"></p:commandLink>
            <br />
            <p:commandLink value="previous"></p:commandLink>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="tab3">
            <h:commandLink value="click"></h:commandLink>
            <br />
            <h:commandLink value="next"></h:commandLink>
            <br />
            <h:commandLink value="previous"></h:commandLink>

        </p:tab>

        </p:accordionPanel> 

         </h:from>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when there is no value coming form ManagedBean.
Verify if the `#{Bean.store}` is generated correctly or not.
Or remove `acticeIndex` attribute.

Comment: Thanks fr ur comment Kishor. i tried it , but again its not working !!if i give commandlink instead of commandbutton , then its working

Comment: can u guys let me know why ?